# Special symbols in string c#

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, symbols

I receive json from server: `response: {text: 'Rize &ndash; The Orchid (Original Mix)'}`
and after `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonR>(responseFromServer);`

and get "Rize &_ndash;(without _) The Orchid (Original Mix)"

how I can get this string "Rize – The Orchid (Original Mix)"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HWrb.png

Comment: Use HtmlEncode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "symbol" is an html entity which needs to be decoded. You can use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
  var str = "{text: 'Rize &ndash; The Orchid (Original Mix)'}";
  str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);      
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MockObject>(str);
```